# Python Regex - Split on a repeated match?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings:

```
{topic.equals(org.fedoraproject.prod.bodhi.buildroot_override.tag), foo.notequals(bar)}
{topic.in(1,2,3), foo.equals(baz)}
```

and I want to get the results:

```
["topic.equals(org.fedoraproject.prod.bodhi.buildroot_override.tag)", "foo.notequals(bar)"]
["topic.in(1,2,3)", "foo.equals(baz)"]
```

What is within the curlies is unlimited but the basic match needs be:

```
<key>.<command>(<args>)
```

so there could be 15 matches inside the curlies.

Comment: can args be nested at all?

Comment: No, the args will just be comma separated

Comment: Your first line is missing the closing curly brace, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep this as simple as possible:

```
entries = []
for line in inputsource:
    entries.append(map(str.strip, line.strip().strip('{}').split(', ')))
```

So, for each line, strip whitespace then curly braces, then split on the comma-plus-space separating the commands and store the whitespace-stripped results.

This relies on the fact that the commands are separated by a comma plus a space, while the arguments in your sample only use commas without spaces. If you have anything that violates that difference, then you do need to resort to a regular expression. I'd limit it to the split only though:

```
import re
commandsep = re.compile(r'(?<=\)),\s*')

for line in inputsource:
    entries.append(map(str.strip, commandsep.split(line.strip().strip('{}'))))
```

The `commandsep` expression splits on any comma-plus-optional-whitespace, provided it was preceded by a `)` closing parenthesis (using a look-behind assertion).

For your input that results in:

```
>>> entries
[['topic.equals(org.fedoraproject.prod.bodhi.buildroot_override.tag)', 'foo.notequals(bar)'], ['topic.in(1,2,3)', 'foo.equals(baz)']]
```

If these entries are embedded in a larger body of text, then a regular expression might help, but only to find the curly-brace-delimited values:

```
import re

expression = re.compile(r'{[^{}]+}')
inputsource = expression.findall(largerbodyoftext)
```

where `expression` will find any text delimited by curly braces (no nesting).

Comment: This doesn't quite work, you'll notice in your section: 

['topic.in(1', '2', '3)', 'foo.equals(baz)']

the first string is 'topic.in(1'  which isn't valid, it should be 'topic.in' and then '1', '2', '3'  OR one solid string that I can use a regex on 'topic.in(1,2,3)'

Comment: @sontek: ick, right. Parsing fun. For your *specific example* adding a space to the split is all that is needed though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works but would like opinions since it isn't very elegant:

```
column_regex = re.compile("\w+\.\w+\(.+?\)")
results = re.findall(column_regex, data)
```

which will give the results of the commands inside the {}:

```
['topic.equals(org.fedoraproject.prod.bodhi.buildroot_override.tag)', 'foo.notequals(bar)']
```

and then you can use a 2nd regex on each returned value:

```
filter_regex = re.compile("^(?P<column>\w+)\.(?P<command>\w+)\((?P<args>.+?)\)")
```

to be able to do a match and get the values:

```
filter_match = re.match(filter_regex, match)
filter_match.group('command')
```